# Is there a way to create dynamic variable names in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, naming

If I create a `student` class and each time a new student object is created, how do I dynamically create a new variable name to distinguish between the different students? I don't know how many students there will be.

On the last line of the code below I have used `student1` as the variable name for the new student object. If I want to create 100 student objects and have the variable name be `student1` through `student100` how would I dynamically create these variable names?

```rb
class Student
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    puts "Hello #{name}"
  end
end

puts "What is your name?"
answer = gets.chomp
student1 = Student.new(answer)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use an array for holding those 100 student objects, each new object creation will be added into that array, then you can access them via index

Comment: this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/319720), you really want to use an array like Nguyen said

Comment: To anwer your question, since Ruby v1.9 it has not been possible to create a local variable dynamically. In earlier versions that could be done using `eval`.

Comment: @NathanWorden : Creating a variable - dynamically or not - means that you later access the variable in your program by its *name*; otherwise, why create it in the first place? Then I don't see what advantage you have from a dynamical creation. If you want to handle a collection of objects and still somehow give a "name" to the individual objects, use a Hash and make the "name" the hash key.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
students = Array.new(100) { |i| Student.new("Name #{i}") }
```

If you want to access the student i<sup>th</sup>, you can call

```
students[i]
```

There's no need to create a local variable called students_13 for example.

The first student is `student[0]`, the last one `student[99]`.